# How to split sql query results into new incremental tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following code to create a HTML table which works great to produce a table ordered by position based on points. However, I would like to sub divide the results into different tables with incremental names. For example, the first 20 results will be Table 1, the next 20 records will be table 2 and so on. I need it to be dynamic because the total number of records will be different each time the query runs.

```
SELECT name,team, points,
         (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS position
    
   FROM results AS t, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS r
   ORDER BY points DESC
```

I would appreciate advice on the best way to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This is definitely not standard SQL.  Also, very few databases allow you to insert into multiple different tables in a single statement, so you probably cannot do exactly what you want.

Comment: You say you use the "...following code to create a table..." but the query is performing a `select` not `create`. And when you say "...sub divide the results into different tables..." do you just mean you want to group the rows? I'm not sure your use of the word "table" is correct.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have updated the tag with mysql. I am not looking to insert into the database but show the data in several different tables with incremental numbers table 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Specify precise version of your MySQL server.

Comment: @Tony sorry I should have said creating a HTML table using the select statement. I have edited it thanks.

Comment: @Akina, I am using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: I have asked about MySQL server version. Execute `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: @Akina, Sorry I am new to this, 10.4.14-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this (for 20 rows per page/table):

```sql
SELECT name,team, points,
       (@row_number := (@row_number MOD 20) + 1) AS position,
       (@page_number := @page_number + (@row_number = 1)) AS page
FROM results AS t, (SELECT @row_number := 0б @page_number := 0) AS r
ORDER BY points DESC
```

PS. The `points` column values must be unique, if not then the order of the rows with the same value is unpredictable (in such case you may expand sorting expression for to provide uniqueness, for example, use `ORDER BY points, id`).

---

> 10.4.14-MariaDB – f1inshot

Your query should be

```sql
SELECT name,team, points,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points) AS position
FROM results AS t
ORDER BY position;
```

and respectively

```sql
SELECT name,team, points,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points) MOD 20) AS position,
       ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points) + 19) DIV 20) AS page
FROM results AS t
ORDER BY page, position;
```

And the same - if `ponts` is not unique use expanded ORDER BY in window definitions.

Comment: thanks for your input. I am working with the info you provided. I need to do some more research as this is not giving the results I was looking for, but its a great help. Thanks

Comment: @f1inshot You have not provided precise desired result so I post the solution for the task as I understand it...

Comment: @Akina.Thank you, your answer works brilliantly. I now understand your answer, very many thanks for your help. It was the 06 that threw me on line 5 in your first answer which works well if I remove the 6. The last solution works well but one record is given the position 0 for a reason I cannot understand. Thanks again.